# Getter function that won't crash when object not found

Tags: c++

I have a class that contains a member variable which is a list of custom objects. I am trying to write a getter function which looks through this list trying to find one with the provided name. I would like to return said object by constant reference if found, or just output "Object with name "name" not found." otherwise, without crashing my program. Any ideas? I'm thinking I could make another function that simply returns a boolean if a matching object exists, and calling that first. If it returns true, then get the given item. However, this is inefficient, and I would like to do better.

Comment: Can you use `std::list` and `std::find()`?

Answer (score 2):

Options:

- Throw an exception when not found - catch it in the caller
- Return an iterator - check for `== .end()` to determine if not found in the caller (STL does this)
- Have the function return a pointer and return `NULL` if not found
- Have a special object indicating not found and return a reference to that when not found
- Check for existence beforehand (as you mentioned)

Comment: I'd take an `optional` wrapper over the pointer. It prevents the extra copy and the heap-allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The idea that you have of separating existence check and value retrival, is sound.

It's not inherently inefficient, and anyway, why not try it on and see whether it turns out to be a bottleneck or not? and if the first impelmentation does seem to be inefficient, just cache a hint or perhaps the whole result of the check

Otherwise your options include throwing an exception when not found, and using some implementation of the Baron/Nackman `Fallible` class as function result, such as `boost::optional` (or just roll your own)

And, thinking about it, you can just return a pointer. That can be awkward for pointer or array object type, but generally should be perhaps the cleanest solution. Return a nullpointer to signal "object not found".

Answer (score 0):

You can provide 2 versions of accessors, one throws exception, or silently returning empty object, another has parameter to report, that data does not exist:

```
class Props {
public:
    const Object &get( const std::string &name ) const; // throws exception or silently retruns empty
    const Object &get( const std::string &name, bool &found ) const; // returns flag
};
```

In C++11 it could be cleaner:

```
class Props {
public:
    const Object &get( const std::string &name, bool &&found = bool() ) const;
};
```

I would take it back for C++11 version, I am not very familiar with new language features, this does not seem to be cleaner.